# Pandas - Spitting data (lists) from multiple columns into new row

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe that has lots stored in each column. I am trying to have them unpacked such that each combination is made into a new row. Given below is how my data looks like.

```
cust_id,prod_name,type,value
101,['car','bike','computer'],['t1','t2','t3'],['434','533','55']
102,['car','bike'],['t1','t3'],['533','55']
```

Trying to convert the above dataframe to the below format:

```
cust_id,prod_name,type,value
101,car,t1,434
101,bike,t2,533
101,computer,t3,55
102,car,t1,533
102,bike,t3,55
```

Comment: have you updated your pandas to 0.25 ?

Comment: @AndyL. not yet but I could have that updated

Comment: In that case, I recommend you update to 0.25 and use its new method `explode`. It's really simple with `explode`

Comment: @AndyL. thanks let me check that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unnest (explode) a column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

There is a great answer for this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/6348485

I would mark this question as a duplicate but I don't think I have enough reputation to do it.

The above is a great answer offering almost 10 different methods.

Comment: Actually I managed to mark this as duplicate via flag. I hope I didn't make too much of a mess and it helps.